# Organizing legacy C projects with Eclipse CDT

Tags: c, unix, eclipse-cdt

I have a big legacy project (C ANSI, coded in early 90s for SCO/Xenix with support to POSIX). This project is based in the following structure:

```
+ h (all common headers)
+ lutil1 (just .c source to build the library)
+ lutil2 (just .c source to build the library)
+ ...(more libs in the same structure)
|
+ moduleA (can have dependency to one or several libs)
|  + several common .h 
|  + several common .c sources 
|  + moduleA-exe1.c (executable depending of some sources in this folder)
|  + moduleA-exe2.c (executable depending of some sources in this folder)
|  + ... (more executables, .c sources with main function)
|
+moduleB (can have dependency to one or several libs)
|  + several common .h 
|  + several common .c sources 
|  + moduleB-exe1.c (executable depending of some sources in this folder)
|  + moduleB-exe2.c (executable depending of some sources in this folder)
|  + ... (more executables, .c sources with main function)
|
|...
```

Each module can have dozens of executable, others have a lot of common .c and few executable. And there are dozens of modules.

This project can be build through legacy scripts, but now with gcc and gmake, but isn't very good yet, we're migrating slowly, without big modifications in the structure to keep the scripts working.

Now, we're promoting the use of the IDE "Eclipse with CDT", and the concept of one project to each executable ins't very easy to adapt in this project (look the modules organization).

Is there a way to keep multiple executables sources in the same folder mapped to several eclipse projects each one ? More suggestions are welcome.

**NOTE:** Keep in mind that we need to have the legacy scripts working for some time until we are sure that the new organization/structure/technology can build all binaries effectively.

Comment: You are creating a problem by insisting to use an editor as a build-tool. Why not improve on the existing `make` infrastructure? (see http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf for hints on how *not* to use Make)

Comment: Thanks by the make paper. It was what I keep searching for since some years ago.

Comment: If you want to take a peek: PostgreSQL has a rather nice and clean (g)make build&install, even with autoconf. Aimed to work at different platforms. (works on a Raspberry Pi, too!)

Answer (score 0):

For the modules which have several executable sources (main()), we created a new folder to hold all new eclipse cdt projects that are each one mapped to their respective files, using linked file, it's a pain to do, but is what we found as a workaround.

The linked file can be relative to workspace, extending variables.